# Convert Postgres IPv6 column TEXT field into JSON

Tags: sql, postgresql

Trying to convert a **text** field to a **JSON** field in Postgres. The field was an IPv6 address those having multiple semicolons e.g.: *"14:eth1:vTA1:::4:"*

Trying to run smth like:

```
ALTER TABLE data ALTER COLUMN ipv6 TYPE jsonb USING ipv6::jsonb;
```

Results in:

> Failed to convert text field to JSON. Details: invalid input syntax for type json
> DETAIL:  Expected end of input, but found ":".

Any clues how to do it properly?

Comment: Any reason to not use INET type? It is specifically designed to store and manipulate ipv4/ipv6 addresses

Comment: If you really want it to be JSON or JSONB you’ll have to make sure it is valid JSON. Do you want it as a string or how?

Comment: Unfortunately, it is not alway a valid JSON. For example, it can be something like "162:eth0:service-chain-ta:::4". As `text` it was stored without a problems. It has to be stored as `jsonb`.

Comment: What do you expect the jsonb document to look like?  Can you please edit your question to provide an example?  Do you just want it to be a valid `jsonb` string?

Comment: @0leg: that string can be valid json if you format it properly (quote string properly). That said, your string format is not valid ipv6, you better not call it ipv6 at all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use to_jsonb rather than ::jsonb.

```
ALTER TABLE data ALTER COLUMN ipv6 TYPE jsonb USING to_jsonb(ipv6);
```